# IXIA IxLoad TCL API enablehttpproxy

Tags: tcl, http-proxy

I have turned on the enablehttpproxy flag on IxLoad TCL API, however, the traffic does not go through http proxy, instead it goes to Server address. I don't know why. :-(

I have no problem using IxLoad GUI sending traffic towards http proxy, but not working with TCL API.

this is part of my IxLoad TCl code:

```
# Configuring Activity newAgent1
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
$Activity_newAgent1 agent.config \
    -cookieRejectProbability 0.0 \
    -enableUnidirectionalClose false \
    -ipPreference 2 \
    -loopValue true \
    -maxPersistentRequests 1 \
    -enableEsm 0 \
    -certificate "" \
    -sequentialSessionReuse 0 \
    -tos 0 \
    -maxPipeline 1 \
    -maxHeaderLen 1024 \
    -maxSessions 3 \
    -enableHttpProxy 1 \
    -enableTos false \
    -enable 1 \
    -browserEmulation 1 \
    -cookieJarSize 10 \
    -privateKey "" \
    -privateKeyPassword "" \
    -urlStatsCount 10 \
    -followHttpRedirects 0 \
    -tcpCloseOption 0 \
    -enableVlanPriority false \
    -esm 1460 \
    -httpVersion 1.0 \
    -sslVersion 3 \
    -name "newClientActivity1" \
    -enableCookieSupport 0 \
    -enableLargeHeader true \
    -clientCiphers "DEFAULT" \
    -httpProxy ":8080" \
    -keepAlive 0 \
    -httpsProxy "1.0.0.1:8080"

    $Activity_newAgent1 agent.actionList.clear
```

Comment: I reformatted your question - to put in large blocks of code such as yours, you should precede each line with four spaces rather than place the code between backticks\grave accents - that doesn't seem to scale properly!

Comment: As to an answer - I'm afraid I can't help. I had a look at the [ixia website](http://www.ixiacom.com), but you seem to need an account to access the manuals - do they have a helpdesk you could call? The _only_ thing that looks in the least odd about your code above is that you appear to specify the httpProxy as `:8080` should you be specifying an IP address as well as port? Even if it's documented as not required, it might be worth trying to specify the address to see if it fixes things. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Nurdglaw, thanks for helping me modifying the code. I did try httpProxy "1.0.0.1:8080" as well, it doesn't work either for me. :-( Because the support service is expired, I have not renewed it yet.